# Missing Library com.sun.tools.attach

Tags: java, virtual-machine, jdk-tools

I've tried to follow [this tutorial](http://dhruba.name/2010/02/07/creation-dynamic-loading-and-instrumentation-with-javaagents/), but I have problem with imports.

I got:

```
The import com.sun.tools cannot be resolved
```

in line

```
import com.sun.tools.attach.VirtualMachine;
```

I've tried to look for some info on Sun/Oracle website, but I have not found anything helpful.

I am developing on JDK 1.6.0_31.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`tools.jar` needs to be added to the IDE's library path and the program's classpath.  The `tools.jar` file is found in the JDK's `lib` directory.

For example, if the JDK were installed into `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_11` then the `tools.jar` file will be found at `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_11\lib\tools.jar`.

Answer (score 4):

You should add `tools.jar` to your `classpath`.

Answer (score 4):

Refer this tutorial to include  `tools.jar` .

http://hobione.wordpress.com/2009/03/11/missing-comsuntoolsjar142/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.